# Giving one hint for each of the tries (guessing number game)

Tags: python

I am making a game which requires the user to enter a number. They get four tries, and if they get the number wrong, they get a hint.

How can I try to give only one hint for each of the four tries the user has to get the number right? For example, after the user gets the first try wrong, I would like the program to display the `even_or_odd` hint.

```
from random import randrange
new_number = randrange(1, 101)

class Hints:
    def __init__(self, new_number):
        self.new_number = new_number
        
    def even_or_odd(self):
        if self.new_number % 2 == 0:
            print('Hint. The number is even.')
        else:
            print('Hint. The number is odd.')
            
    def multiple3to5(self):
        for x in range(3, 6):
            n = self.new_number % x
        if n == 0:
            print(f'Hint. The number is a multiple of {x}', end = ' ' )
            
    def multiple6to10(self):
        for x in range(6, 11):
            n = self.new_number % x
        if n == 0:
            print(f'Hint. The number is a multiple of x {x}', end = ' ')




print('Guess a number beteen 1 and 100.')
hint = Hints(new_number)

for x in range(1, 5):
    is_answer_given = False
    while not is_answer_given:
        try:
            user_input = int(input(f'Attempt {x}: '))
            is_answer_given = True
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a numerical value.')
            
    if user_input == new_number and x == 1:    #hint after first attempt
        print('You win!')
        break
    else:
        print('Incorrect!')
        hint.even_or_odd()
        
    if user_input == new_number and x == 2:    #hint after second attempt
        print('You win!')
        break
    else:
        print('Incorrect!')
        hint.multiple3to5()
        
    if user_input == new_number and x == 3:   #hint after third attempt
        print('You win!')
        break
    else:
        print('Incorrect!')
        hint.multiple6to10()
    
    if x == 4:
        print('You are out of attempts!')
        print(f'The number was {new_number}')
        break
```

Comment: So you are trying to guess the number that you input into the `Hints()` constructor i.e. `new_number` by using `user_input`. even with the logic of the hints they only check for multiples/odd/even., how are you going to guess the number?

Comment: Please explain how your current code doesn't do what you want.  From your general structure, it appears that you have done this correctly.  Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the indentation in the "multiple"-methods, too. Shouldn't the `if` clause be inside the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make one if statement that checks for the correct answer. In the else statement you can use if - elif statements to check for the attempt number.

```py
if user_input == new_number:
    print('You win!')
    break
else:
    print('Incorrect!')
    if x == 1:
        hint.even_or_odd()
    elif x == 2:
        hint.multiple3to5()
    elif x == 3:
        hint.multiple6to10()
    else:
        print('You are out of attempts!')
        print(f'The number was {new_number}')
```

The reason you see multiple hints on attempt is that for multiple if statements their condition is not true, so their 'else' block is run

Comment: On a side note, there seems to be a wrong indentation in functions for checking divisibility. `if n == 0:` should be inside a for statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a neat trick:

```py
from random import randrange

new_number = randrange(1, 101)

class Hints:
    def __init__(self, new_number):
        self.new_number = new_number
        self.choices = {
            1: self.even_or_odd,
            2: self.multiple3to5,
            3: self.multiple6to10
        }
        
    def run(self,key):
        action = self.choices.get(key)
        action()
        
    def even_or_odd(self):
        if self.new_number % 2 == 0:
            print('Hint. The number is even.')
        else:
            print('Hint. The number is odd.')
            
    def multiple3to5(self):
        for x in range(3, 6):
            n = self.new_number % x
        if n == 0:
            print(f'Hint. The number is a multiple of {x}', end = ' ' )
        else:
           print("Well, Not a multple of 3 or 5")

            
    def multiple6to10(self):
        for x in range(6, 11):
            n = self.new_number % x
        if n == 0:
            print(f'Hint. The number is a multiple of x {x}', end = ' ')
        else:
           print("Well, Not a multple of 6 or 10")




print('Guess a number beteen 1 and 100.')
hint = Hints(new_number)
print(new_number)
i = 3
win = False
while i >= 1 :
    is_answer_given = False
    while not is_answer_given:
        try:
            user_input = int(input(f'Attempt {i}: '))
            is_answer_given = True
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a numerical value.')
            
    if user_input == new_number:   
        print('You win!, Number is: {new_number}')
        win = True
        break

    hint.run(i)
    i -= 1

if not win:
    print("You lost!")
    print(f"Number is {new_number}")
```